# Starting Main launcher activity from another activity

Tags: android, android-activity

my Main launcher activity (the one that has `android.intent.action.MAIN` as its action) is Login page.

After successful login I started HOME activity and `finish()` the LOGIN one to prevent users returning to that page by pressing BACK button.

When I press SIGN OUT button, I want the app to return to Login page. But I can't find a way to do it. Here's the sign out code:

```
//This method is in HOME activity
private void signOut(){
    Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
    startActivity(i);
    finish();
}
```

That code will open dialog box listing all applications in my phone for me to choose. I tried putting the package name + class name (`com.example.test.Login`) as the Intent but keep getting this error:

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent
```

I know I can trick this problem by using Splash screen as Main activity. But If there is another better solution, I want to know it.

Thanks

Comment: [This](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidIntent/article.html) is quite detailed. I suggest you read it to get a grasp of Intents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, LoginPage.class);
startActivity (i);
finish();
```

Comment: Wow didn't thought that the solution would be that simple. Thanks

Comment: is that Intent i = new Intent(this, LoginPage.class);